# React | localeCompare sort with null values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, antd

I'm using [React ant design table](https://ant.design/components/table/). 
In that table I'm trying to sort with null values by using `localeCompare` It shows Type error.

**JSON**

```
const data = [{
  key: '1',
  name: null,
  age: 32,
}, {
  key: '2',
  name: 'Jim Green',
  age: '32',
}, {
  key: '3',
  name: 'Joe Black',
  age: 32,
}];
```

When I sort I'm getting error like:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of null
```

I have full code on [Code sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/8yv80395zl)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check if your value is `null` then you can assign blank using pipe.

In your code you can do like this

```
{
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name",
    sorter: (a, b) => {
        a = a.name || '';
        b = b.name || '';
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    }
},
```

**DEMO**

```js
const data = [{
  key: '1',
  name: null,
  age: 32,
}, {
  key: '2',
  name: 'Jim Green',
  age: '32',
}, {
  key: '3',
  name: 'Joe Black',
  age: 32,
}];

console.log(data.sort((a,b)=>{
 a= a.name||'';
 b= b.name||'';
 return a.localeCompare(b)
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {  max-height: 100% !important;  top: 0;}
```

Comment: Thank You @N. Jadhav. You saved my day :)

Answer (score 5):

if you have ES2020, there is `optional chaining` to prevent error by returning undefined instead of throwing error when evaluated value is nullish. You can use it like this

```js
arr.sort((a,b) => a?.localeCompare(b))
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Thanks this worked.

const orderedPosts = posts.slice().sort((a, b) => b.date?.localeCompare(a.date))

I had same error with sorting date. but your suggestion worked.